# Getting row label from a table in R

Tags: r

I was working on the `Faithful` built in data set in R and I wanted to find out the interval which had the maximum number of eruptions. I already grouped the data into intervals and using the max() function I get the value of the max eruptions but not the interval. Is there anyway to display the interval which has the maximum number of eruptions?

The table is given below:

```
[1.5,2)      51
[2,2.5)      41
[2.5,3)       5
[3,3.5)       7
[3.5,4)      30
[4,4.5)      73
[4.5,5)      61
[5,5.5)       4
```

Considering here, the max is `73`, how do I print `[4, 4.5)` ?

Comment: what is the code you've used to create this table?

Comment: @Amit Naik

You should provide a reproducible example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your data is hard to reproduce. Something  like this may work
`d <- c(1,3,2,2,1)
which(d == max(d))`

Comment: `names(which.max(table(cut(faithful$eruptions, seq(1.5, 5.5, .5), right = FALSE))))`

Comment: I first found out the range using  'range(faithful$eruptions)' . Then I divided the range into sub-intervals using the 'seq()' function. Then I classified the data into the sub-intervals using the 'cut()' function, which I put in a table.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in a named num `q` like this:

```
> q
[1.5,2) [2,2.5) [2.5,3) [3,3.5) [3.5,4) [4,4.5) [4.5,5) [5,5.5) 
     51      41       5       7      30      73      61       4
```

use `names`:

```
> names(q)[which.max(q)]
[1] "[4,4.5)"
```

If it's in any kind of dataframe/matrix/t `p`, use `rownames`:

```
> p
        max_er
[1.5,2)     51
[2,2.5)     41
[2.5,3)      5
[3,3.5)      7
[3.5,4)     30
[4,4.5)     73
[4.5,5)     61
[5,5.5)      4

> rownames(p)[which.max(p$max_er)]
[1] "[4,4.5)"
```

Comment: @AmitNaik - You could also respond to all the comments under your question, especially those about providing a reproducible example